# where to empty an array in this situation in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, nsmutablearray

I am making a project..

In that I am using a viewController and a tableViewController..

I am declaring two array here, In viewController array1 and in tableViewcontroller array 2

Now I am assinging an array in a view controller and I am giving the values of array 1 to the array 2 in view controller and I am showing that one in the tableViewController

Now my problem is when I am navigating between this two view every time array is added up in the table view..

so what happens is  array is added up every time..

so where should i do removeAllObject process??

Comment: Can you show me your code where you assign the array?

Comment: sorry for late reply chetan..I solved it..:) thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your table view controller make an property for the array.

```
@interface DetailedAddViewController : UITableViewController{
    NSArray *dataSourceArray;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain)    NSArray *dataSourceArray;
@end
```

And in m file don't forget to add

```
@synthesize  dataSourceArray;
```

And in dealloc method to release it

```
[addDictionary release];
```

[Declared Properties doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW13)

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you are switching from one view controller to another.So the view controller loading again.In viewDidload method,initialize a flag and remove an array inside the flag.